# How to get data from Real-Time Database in Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've used the Real-Time Database with this setup:

```
->users
    ->uid
        ->name
        ->email
        ->other info
```

If I wanted to save the user data I would use my User class and then set the object in the database like this:

```
//assume variables have already been declared...

mFirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
mFirebaseUser = mFirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
User user = new User(name, email, other values...);
mDBRef.child("users").child(mFirebaseUser.getUid()).setValue(user);
```

I tried it and it works fine.

But how can I retrieve these values from the database? For instance, once I set a User object as shown above, I may want to retrieve the user's email. I don't mean getting the email through the sign-in provider. I want the email through the real-time database. I've tried working this out for a while now but the documentation isn't helping much. All it shows is to setup listeners in order to wait for changes to the data. But I'm not waiting for changes, I don't want a listener. I want to directly get the values in the database by using the keys in the JSON tree. Is this possible via the real-time database? If so, how can it be done because either the documentation doesn't explain it or I'm just not understanding it. If not possible, am I supposed to be using the Storage database or something else? Thanks.

Comment: The way to get data from your Firebase Database is by attaching a listener. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/retrieve-data

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I believe you are one of the engineers who has worked on Firebase? (Seen you answer many posts on it). If so, I think it would very helpful to add an explanation the way Ian Richard explained in the comments of his answer to the documentation where the listeners are discussed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firebase uses listeners to get data. That is just the nature of how it works. Although, you can use a single event listener (the equivalent of just grabbing the data once). It will fire immediately and get the data, and will not fire ever again. Here's a code example to get the current user's email:

```
//Get User ID
final String userId = getUid();

//Single event listener
mDatabase.child("users").child(userId).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(
    new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            // Get user value
            User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);

            //user.email now has your email value
        }
    });
```

Comment: Okay but my concern is this occurs when data is _changed_, no? What if I haven't added or modified anything in the database but I want the data of some user?

Comment: No, this is a value event listener, and will grab the intended data immediately. The onDataChange method is just grabbing the dataSnapshot, but it is not waiting for anything to be changed.

Comment: Man that is very confusing. I would've never known given the very nature of Listeners in general, and the name "onDataChange". Thanks for the explanation though, it was exactly what I needed!

Comment: Very good stufff.but I have a doubt regarding uid.if i login with same credntials in another device will be the uid same or will be it change

Comment: @NarenderReddy I barely saw this comment. But yes, the Uid will be the same across any device using any platform ( Android, iOS, and web) once it it is stored to the database. The data is stored in the cloud so using Firebase's simple email/password login feature, it retrieves that Uid from the database. Thus the data remains the same across any device and platform.