# sql like query in firebase

Tags: android, sql, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE CustomerName LIKE '%or%'
```

here is a sql query i want same query for firebase i google it but not find a helpful answer.
one more thing i want to use this query for android

Comment: Firebase is noSQL!

Comment: i know bro but i give example i want this type work

Comment: check the given link:- http://stackoverflow.com/a/39025129/2779561

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22506531/how-to-perform-sql-like-operation-on-firebase?rq=1 (the first link in the Related column).