# Firebase Query an Array index value in Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How to list all `recent` where `members`  `0`th index equal to `"5"`?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firebase querying data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39024702/firebase-querying-data)

Comment: @NileshRathod which didn't work for my scenario. The below answer is the correct one. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("recent");
Query query = ref.orderByChild("members/0").equalTo("5");
query.addValueListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            System.out.println(childSnapshot.getKey());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {            
        throw databaseError.toException());
    }
});
```

The trick here is that you specify the relative *path* to the property that you want to order/filter on in `orderByChild()`.